# Unable to install the IPA file in the iPad Air 4

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, ipa

Recently, I was trying to install the IPA file in my ipad air 4. The IPA file was shared via beta family as well as diawi. While I was opening these links in safari browser, it was downloading IPA file instead of installing. I install their profiles multiple time but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured out that safari has a setting Request Desktop Website on which was stopping me to install IPA. I turned this settings off and opened the beta family or diawi link from safari and it was showing me install option instead of download. I spent almost a day to figure this out and hoping someone to save their time from this question.